# facebook login but include error

Tags: php, facebook

I have a facebook login code, but I want to integrate a php include code and every time after login if I refresh the page then it again say login

`<?php include "info.php";?>`

the code is given below

```
<html>
 <head>
 <script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.10.2/jquery.min.js"></script>    
 <script src="https://connect.facebook.net/en_US/all.js"></script>

<script>
$( document ).ready(function() {
    $('#logoutBtn').hide();
    $('#userDetails').hide();
});

function fbAsyncInit() {
    FB.init({
        appId      : 'XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX',
        status     : true, // check login status
        cookie     : true, // enable cookies to allow the server to access the session
        xfbml      : true  // parse XFBML
    });
}
function logIn() {
    FB.login(
        function(response) {
            if (response.status== 'connected') {
                FB.api('/me', function(response) {
                    console.log(response);
                    console.log('Good to see you, ' + response.name + '.');
                    $('#loginBtn').hide();
                    $('#logoutBtn').show();
                    $('#userDetails').show();
                    $('#userInfo').html(response.name + '<br>' + response.location.name);
                });

                FB.api("/me/picture?width=200&redirect=0&type=normal&height=200", function (response) {
                    if (response && !response.error) {
                        /* handle the result */
                        console.log('PIC ::', response);
                        $('#userPic').attr('src', response.data.url);
                    }
                });
            }
        }
    );
}

function logOut() {
    FB.logout(function(response) {
        console.log('logout :: ', response);
        //Removing access token form localStorage.
        $('#loginBtn').show();
        $('#logoutBtn').hide();
        $('#userDetails').hide();
    });
}

fbAsyncInit();

</script>
</head>
<body>

<div id="userDetails">
<img src="" id="userPic" />
<div id="userInfo"></div>
</div>
<button id="loginBtn" onclick="logIn();" value="Login">Login</button>
<button id="logoutBtn" onclick="logOut();" value="Logout">Logout</button>
</body>
</html>
```

now I need help to get this problem solved

Comment: Can you please post piece of code where you check login data in your db?

Comment: actually I got it from google but do not get any db file yet

Comment: You just copied fb login script. It's ok but now it just checks if user is logged in and if no it asks user to login. If yes it gives you credentials so you can check user and start a session. Fb doesn't give you that piece of code. You must write it.

Comment: ok do I need to create a db and config??

Comment: I don't know for what are you using fb login but I assume that you want let people have access to part of your page only if they are logged in.  I would create db and store user data. If they login with fb I would take credentials and store it in same db. When they come back I would check credentials and start a session.

Comment: yea... for submit form, I do not wanna allow any person to submit the form without login

Comment: So take fb login data provided with code you found on fb login api pages and store values in db. When you check email, name etc then start a session. Check if session is started and if yes show the form.

Comment: actually I can not understand the fb developer instruction properly... thats why I am searching in google

Comment: https://developers.facebook.com/docs/facebook-login/web start here. Everything is explained.

Comment: yea, i do this..., but page is plank still now

Comment: got it, but, a porblem is that, i want this session in different page also, that means, without login, no one can see the 2nd page also

Comment: So you have to check if session is started in 2nd page too

Comment: no, when i set the `<?php session_start(); ?>` it does not working, i can see without login

Comment: can you give me the session code please

Comment: You have to check if session is started.
if (session_status() == PHP_SESSION_NONE) {

Comment: please check this question. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/35097443/use-facebook-login-session-on-another-page

Comment: You don't need to open another question. Just edit this one. I didn't understand your question. What did you tried and what do you need?

Comment: i create a login, and i have another page where i want to add this session, so if someone login via facebook, he can see the page's material, if he is not log in by the facebook account then he can not see any material of the page

Comment: My idea is that when you register user via Facebook you set it db with boolean true. Than when you check if session is started check if Facebook login row is true for that user.

Comment: yea, can you give any demo link for this.....

Comment: There is no demo link. This requires complete user registration code.